# how to set images in listview with listactivity?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I want to set imagese in listview but I don't do it properly. What's wrong with images I dont know .plz help me my code is here.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> dataListfeture = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for(int j=0; j<nodesfeture.getLength(); j++)
        {
            Element e1 =(Element)nodesfeture.item(j);
            Node node = nodesfeture.item(j);
            HashMap<String, String> mapfeautre = new HashMap<String, String>();


            mapfeautre.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
            String rename = mapfeautre.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
            rename.replaceAll("", "%20");
            mapnamelist= mapfeautre.put("name",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
            mapfeautre.put("distance",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("distance").getNodeValue());
            mapdistancelist =mapfeautre.put("distance",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("distance").getNodeValue());
            mapfeautre.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
            mapvenuelist=mapfeautre.put("venuetype",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("venuetype").getNodeValue());
        mapfeautre.put("imageupload",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("imageupload").getNodeValue());
        String strimageurl=mapfeautre.put("imageupload",node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("imageupload").getNodeValue());
        mapimagelist="http://www.afterdarknightlife.com/"+strimageurl;
        System.out.println("Image URL "+j+" :"+mapimagelist);

            mylistfeature.add(mapfeautre);

        }
        System.out.println("data list = "+dataListfeture);


        ListAdapter adapterfeaturetype = new SimpleAdapter(MainScreen.this, mylistfeature, R.layout.demophoto, new String[]
        {
          "imageupload","name", "distance","venuetype
        },
        new int[]
        {
                R.id.item_featureimage,
                R.id.item_featurename,
                R.id.item_featuredistance,
                R.id.item_featurevenuetype,


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give [GreedDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) a try. It has very advanced set of list view items (including an item with an image) which you can use from code and from xml as well.

Comment: help me guys m getting data from webservice nt local array data plz help me how can i set image in listview

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you...

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: guys help me m fetching data from url not simple araay data